# Pascal's law vs buoyancy force in case of hydraulic jack

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

According to pascal's law as the pressure applied in a closed container will be equally distributed in all directions, we have a mechanical advantage of pushing the piston of large cross sectional area when we push the piston of small cross-sectional area in hydraulic lift. But my doubt based on the below diagram is

[image]

When there is no load on the piston P1, the fluid level on both piston P1, P2 be at same height in the markings A, B. Now suppose the car with some mass m be placed on P1 it will displace the fluid of volume equal to the weight mg due to buoyancy force and come to rest in the level of the markings C and D for both pistons. It is clear that a small change in height of P1 from B to D changes a greater change in height in P2 from A to C due to small cross sectional area in P2 to accommodate the volume of fluid pushed in P1. Now to push the car again to the level B we have to apply the same force mg in P2 to push the same volume of liquid displaced by buoyancy force, how there will be the advantage of applying less force in the P2 to lift the car?

Also to lift the car to greater height from B, to say F we may have to apply force to move the P2 up to marking E to displace the liquid in P1. Also now it is clear that for small change in height of P1 we need to push P2 to greater heights and also as the height increases pressure increases at the bottom. so the pressure may be equally distributed at the level/depth/height of applying force but as the depth increases the pressure will be increased, so P2 will have more pressure collectively summed up as it has more depth and P1 will have less pressure collectively summed up as it has less depth. So the less force applied at P2, ie the mechanical advantage will be reduced/cancelled by the pressure due its large depth.

This is my understanding.Am I right? I don't have chance to practically see the hydraulic lift. So through which mechanism in hydraulic lift they are using the advantage of pascal's law.